# calling an api inside map function In node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

```
const processInboundEmailAttachment = async (files: any[]): Promise<any[]> => {

  const attachments = []

  await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      try {

        let response = null

        response = await axios.get(file.url, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "message/rfc2822"
          },
          auth: {
            username: "api",
            password: "api-key"
          },
          responseType: "stream"
        })

        if (response && response.data) {

          response.data.pipe(concat(async data => {
            try {
              const mediaUrl = await uploadToFirestore(file["content-type"], data, file.name)

              attachments.push({
                name: file.name,
                url: mediaUrl,
                id : uuidv4()
              })

            } catch (error) {
              console.log("err", error);
            }

          }));

        }

      } catch (err) {
        log.error(err)
      }
    })
  )

  return attachments // from here this return initial attachments [] array

}

 const uploadAttachment = async () => {
 const attachment =  await processInboundEmailAttachment(JSON.parse(attach))

 console.log("attachment",attachment);
 // I want updated pushed attachment array here but I got [] initial decalare value 
}

app.get("/uploadAttachment", uploadAttachment)
```

In attachment console log I got [] array , It's return initial assign values of array.
It's not wait for API response and newly pushed array.

I think There Is an some issue in Promise , It's not wait for updated array , It's
return directly initialy attachment array

**Thank you for Help In advnace**

Comment: **Actual Output** :- ```[ ]```
 **Expected Output** :-  ```[{name,url,id}{name,url,id}....]```

Comment: What is `concat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not waiting for `uploadFirestore` response. You can cut down your function something like below and wrap it custom `promise`.

```
const processInboundEmailAttachment = async (files: any[]): Promise<any[]> => {
  const getFileUploadedResult = function(file) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let response = null
        response = await axios.get(file.url, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "message/rfc2822"
          },
          auth: {
            username: "api",
            password: "api-key"
          },
          responseType: "stream"
        })
        if (response && response.data) {
          response.data.pipe(concat(async data => {
            try {
              const mediaUrl = await uploadToFirestore(file["content-type"], data, file.name)
              resolve({
                name: file.name,
                url: mediaUrl,
                id : uuidv4()
              })
            } catch (error) {
              reject(err)
            }
          }));
        }
      } catch (err) {
        log.error(err)
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  }
 return Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      return getFileUploadedResult(file)
    })
  )
}

 const uploadAttachment = async () => {
 const attachment =  await processInboundEmailAttachment(JSON.parse(attach))

 console.log("attachment",attachment);
 // I want updated pushed attachment array here but I got [] initial decalare value 
}

app.get("/uploadAttachment", uploadAttachment)
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! You might need `new Promise` here, but it still should be used to promisify only the smallest part that uses an async callback.

Comment: @Bergi do you mean instead of using Promise.all turn that with for...of with async await

Comment: No, I mean that you should [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)